# What does marker.lifetime = rospy.Duration() do?

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simple question :

What effect does `marker.lifetime = rospy.Duration()` have to a marker?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344835/what-does-marker.lifetime-=-rospy.duration()-do?/) by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2020-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As it is stated in the msg [definition](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html):

*"How long the object should last before being automatically deleted.  0 means forever"*

Basically is the amount of time the marker will last.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-05-14**:
Consider the following piece of code -

```
ros::Publisher vis_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>( "visualization_markers", 10 );
vis_pub.publish(marker);
```

Since the above mentioned bit of code is **not** inside a `while` loop `( while (ros::ok()) { .... publish ... } )`, the `publisher` would `publish` just **once** on the topic `viualisation_markers`.

Assume that the `marker` object has the `lifetime` attribute set to `0`. Would that mean that `Rviz` would continue to display the marker?

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2021-05-14**:
@skpro19 Indeed, One thing is the publishing time and another thing is the life time of the marker displayed on Rviz. Basically, in the hypothetical case you proposed, even if the marker is published once, Rviz will continue displaying the same marker with the same state, until you force a marker deletion, GUI Reset or clean the topic (by enabling/disabling the topic with the check mark), in that cases the marker item will be recycled by Rviz by deleting it from screen.